# PDO queries not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a set of PDO statements that do not seem to be working. Basically I am trying to update the "waiting" value in 1 table and then select that same row and insert it into another table.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE waiting SET wait = :status WHERE id = :id");
$statement->bindValue(':status', 0);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->execute();
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type) (SELECT fname, lname, student_id, email, type FROM waiting WHERE id = :id)");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->execute();
```

I've also tried setting `$statement` to null before I do the other query but that didn't work either:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE waiting SET wait = :status WHERE id = :id");
$statement->bindValue(':status', 0);
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->execute();
$statement = null;
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type) (SELECT fname, lname, student_id, email, type FROM waiting WHERE id = :id)");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->execute();
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Define "didn't work." Did neither query execute properly? Do you get an error message from `$statement->errorInfo()`?

Comment: Your [INSERT-Query (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) is wrong: `INSERT INTO approved (...) **VALUES** (...)`

Comment: @Saxoier: values is only required when inserting literals. In an `INSERT... SELECT ...` query it's actually illegal syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted the error. It was a general SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert query is syntactically wrong. Remove the brackets from around the select and it should work:

```
INSERT INTO approved (fname, lname, student_id, email, type)
SELECT fname, lname, student_id, email, type FROM waiting WHERE id = :id
```